# genymotion freezes when running project vscode

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, genymotion

genymotion freezes when running project vscode

`E/eglCodecCommon( 2858): goldfish_dma_create_region: could not obtain fd to device! fd -1 errno=2`

Hardware :

- Intel core i5 6200U
- ram 16 GB
- Intel(R) HD 520

[image]